# Bash-Shell Script aborts without error

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos6

On Debian is the following code working, but on CentOS it just aborts without any errors. What is the error? I can't understand it.

```
    echo "Test 1"
    ANSWER=""
    read -p "Enter y or n " ANSWER;
    echo "Test 2"
```

The output looks allways like that:

```
    Test 1
```

I also tried the read command without the parameter -p, but that's also not working:

```
    echo "Test 1"
    ANSWER=""
    echo "Enter y or n "
    read ANSWER;
    echo "Test 2"
```

Output:

```
    Test 1
    Enter y or n
```

If I execute the command at the command line is it working, how it should. The script has following "headline": #!/bin/bash

Can somebody help?

Comment: What is output of `type read`?

Comment: @anubhava "read is a shell builtin" - on both systems

Comment: does it abort back to your shell, or is it waiting for input?  It may be a buffering issue.

Comment: Which shell are you using to execute the script? Put the hashbang in the beginning to make sure you are using bash `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @Donovan it abort back to my shell. It's not waiting for any input.

Comment: @JarosławJaryszew This line is written in the first line of the whole script...

Comment: @user2966991: you should be more accurate in your description. In a comment to an answer you mention that you include `set -e`, which makes a big difference. You also mentioned there a `while` loop...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@[user2966991](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2966991/user2966991) - The script which reads from stdin is inside a bigger while loop which reads a file through stdin. This will not work. Try redirecting your stdin to a different file handler.

Consider this sample code. This will not work becuase both the while loop and read are reading from stdin.

```
#!/bin/bash
cat samplefile | while read line; do
    read -p "$line (y/n)?" ANSWER
done
```

Now consider this other code.

```
#!/bin/bash
# save stdin to file descriptor 5
exec 5<&0

cat samplefile | while read line; do
    read -p "$line (y/n)?" ANSWER <&5
done

# restore stdin and close file descriptor 5
exec 0<&5 5>&-
```

Personally I prefer input redirection than pipe.

```
cat file | while read var; do
...
done
```

can be written as

```
while read var; do
...
done < file
```

Next time please post your script here or you will not get any answer.

Comment: @user3088572 Awesome! Thank you very much! But I've two questions to your solution. 1. Is a descriptor something like a pointer to a storage address in C++? And if I informed me right, I can use the descripter 3 to 9 also or? 2. Why do you prefer input redircetion than pipe? Are there any performance increase?

Comment: Yes it is a pointer to a FILE. Descriptor 0 is stdin, 1 is stdout, and 2 is stderr. You definitely can use 3 to 9. By using input redirection I avoid running extra processes that would've been detrimental to a sluggish heavily loaded servers. On a healthy system, you won't notice the difference.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Test 1"
read -p "Enter y/n: " ANSWER
echo " Test 2: ${ANSWER}"
```

You didn't need a close on the end of answer.

Comment: It's working as little script, but not in my big script. In the second line of the script is written "set -e". If I comment this it will not abort, but it's also not showing the message with the input. The code looks like that:
        ANSWER=""
        while [[ "$ANSWER" == "" ]]; do
             read -p "Enter y/n: " ANSWER
        fi

Comment: @user2966991 - if it is working as a little script, which I expect, then the issue is not within this block of code. Have you checked if in the big script it fills up the input buffer that somehow gets trickled down to this block?

Comment: In addition, set -e is used for debugging purposes so the script will bail out on error. The script is encountering an error condition that's why it aborts when "set -e" is set.

Comment: @user2966991 this is correct, you will need to go and `#` comment block out portions of your code to see where the problem actually exists.

Comment: @user3088572 How can I check, if the input buffer is filled up? If you want to, you can see the whole code of the script: http://www.forum.ts3-tools.info/index.php?page=Thread&postID=91#post91

Comment: The script in question which reads from stdin is inside a bigger while loop which reads a file through stdin. This will not work. Try redirecting your stdin to a different file handler.